# Loop Through List of Pandas Column Names and Construct Bar Plot with Response Variable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, crosstab

I have a list of column names from my dataframe that I want to create a large subplot grid with. However, I am getting stuck with some indices and am new to `matplotlib` plot syntax. Here is an example of what I am trying and what I want:

Current:

```
from typing import List
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame([['Dog','Dog','Cat', 'Bird'],
                                 ['Cat','Dog','Cat','Bird'],
                                 ['Dog','Cat','Cat','Hamster'],
                                 ['Cat','Cat','Cat','Bird'],
                                 ['Dog','Dog','Dog','Hamster'],
                                 ['Dog','Cat','Dog','Bird']], columns = ['animal1', 'animal2','animal3','animal4'])
print(df)
animal1 animal2 animal3 animal4
0    Dog    Dog Cat        Bird
1    Cat    Dog Cat        Bird
2    Dog    Cat Cat      Hamster
3    Cat    Cat Cat        Bird
4    Dog    Dog Dog      Hamster
5    Dog    Cat Dog        Bird
```

```
list_of_cols: List = ['animal1', 'animal2','animal4']

# construct subplot grid to be populated
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(14,10))
for i, col in enumerate(list_of_cols):
    print(col)
    pd.crosstab(df[col],df['animal3']).plot(kind='bar', ax=axs[i])
    axs[i].set_title('Frequency for '+col)
    axs[i].set_xlabel(col)
    axs[i].set_ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

I am currently getting an  `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'` which I suspect has to do with my indexing of the `axs` object. How would I go about getting this grid populated as I loop through various columns in my data frame that I specify? The more general the solution (for larger grids that I may encounter in my future) the better! Thanks!

Comment: `for ax, col in zip(axs.ravel(), list_of_cols):` and change each instance of `axs[i]` to `ax`.

Comment: @BigBen THis is great. Thanks. However, my subplots seem to overlap (x axis of top row of plots bleeds into plots below). Any idea on how to adjust that?

Comment: `fig.tight_layout()` at the end, before `plt.show()`.

Comment: @BigBen Perfect! You have been a great help. Thanks a ton.